# Add "Date field" in UserCreationForm in Django and connect it to model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a date field in the form.py file and save the data to the User model. After doing the below works, the date field is not showing up. I am stuck on how to process the form data and save it within the view. So I think my form is not working. I am stuck and cannot think of the right code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth

# Create your models here.
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    date = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from . models import User


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    last_date = forms.DateField(label='Last Donated',required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2", "last_date")
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "Display name"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.last_date = self.cleaned_data["last_date"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from accounts.forms import UserCreateForm

# Create your views here.


class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm

    form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        date = form.cleaned_data.get('last_date')
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, date=last_date)

    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

**signup.html**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <form method="POST" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Whats the function of the date field?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django automatically creates two date fields in the user model, date joined(date_joined, and date of last login(last_login). To display date joined in a template use {{ user.date_joined}} or in a view request.user.date_joined

check out the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.date_joined

Comment: Thanks. But I have to do this by Extending User Model. The project I am working on requires adding other fields as well other than DateField.